# Merge iron-ajax responses ( arrays with objects )

Tags: javascript, ajax, polymer

I copied the example of Rob Dodson here in his [Todo-Example](https://youtu.be/1f_Tj_JnStA)
where he has a data-provider element and a view element:

```
<template is="dom-bind">
  <todo-data todos={{todos}}></todo-data>
  <todo-view todos={{todos}}></todo-view>
</template>
```

Inside the todo-data he is using iron-ajax binding it's last-response to {{todos}}.

In my case I also need to append the next "page" to {{todos}} using rest api params offset and limit, so I need to keep track of the actual offset. Resulting in 2 scenarios whether I overwrite {{todos}} with new todos what is quit simple or the appending scenario, that is a little bit confusing:

I need to retarget the scrolling event (fired when hitting lower-threshold of todo-list in todo-view) coming from todo-view to todo-data and then I need to merge the old set of data with the new last-response.

Do I have to:

1. Loop through the new response and use array.push? (ArrayElements are Objects)
2. Listen to on scroll event an fire a new one and listen to the new one inside of todo-data? (for the sake of retargeting)

Thanks in advance

Yours Skeec